# Make a exe for both windows 7 and windows 10(python script)

Tags: python, exe

I have a python project and i converted it to a exe on my desktop(Windows 10) but when i send .exe file to my friend(My friend use Windows 7), IT IS NOT WORKING!

So how can I convert a exe file for Both windows 7 and Windows 10

**Thank you very much!**

Comment: This is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following topic

[Py2exe and psycopg, build on Windows 10, can't run on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881943/py2exe-and-psycopg-build-on-windows-10-cant-run-on-windows-7)

Add this to the options dict in setup.py:

dll_excludes': ['Secur32.dll', 'SHFOLDER.dll', 'CRYPT32.dll']

Comment: can i use pyinstaller here?

Comment: yes, look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54979699/running-python-compiled-as-exe-in-windows-10-run-in-windows-7

Comment: I finished to build my project